# How to clear all entered commands in Terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

How does one clear all the entered commands in terminal?
I am **not** talking about the `clear`command, which merely clears the screen. I want to clear all the commands that I have entered , so the window would completely clean.
I've tried:

```
1. Quitting Terminal
2. Restarting my computer
3. The clear command
```

I am thinking there must be some way, because I've probably entered in about 50 million commands, and there are only 505 in my history.

Comment: The command history is stored in a file, that's why it is persisting. I'm sorry I don't know where that file is in macs but on *nix systems it is usually in `~/` as a dot-file, named depending on what shell you're using.

Comment: In bash, $HISTFILESIZE determines how many commands are kept, typically 500, with older ones being replaced by newer ones. That's why you don't see all commands you've entered. Cameron already said how to clean the history.

Comment: @deed02392, the name is similar on mac, e.g. for bash, it is ~/.bash_history

Answer (score 8):

This should work (at least for bash):

`$ history -c`

Followed by quitting the terminal.

EDIT: Chris Page notes in the comments that quitting the terminal is unnecessary, as there is also a command to clear scrollback in most terminals. On Mac, e.g., this is under `View > Clear Scrollback` or `⌘K`

Comment: Quitting Terminal or closing the terminal window/tab should be completely unnecessary to clear the shell command history.

Comment: The part about quitting the terminal was because the poster wanted to know how to make the window "completely clean". Just clearing the history will only make the history go away, but you can still see what was executed during that login just by scrolling up in most terminal emulators. AFAIK, the only way to get rid of that information is to quit the terminal.

Comment: **View > Clear Scrollback** erases the scrollback text.

Answer (score 7):

**For Mac Terminal user**

delete commands history with the following command

`$ echo '' > ~/.bash_history`

**For Mac zsh user**

delete zsh command history with the following command

`$ echo '' > ~/.zsh_history`

Comment: This is the only solution on this page that worked for me... although it did not apply until after I quit and relaunched the terminal. In other words, use the above command, don't test scrollback or it will re-register it in history. Instead quit terminal, relaunch terminal, and then test he history is successfully deleted. One side effect: the above command will be the sole remaining command in the scrollback history.

Comment: I have tried everything, and only echo '' > ~/.zsh_history worked for me for zsh. Thanks so much for sharing @vikbert Of course. Totally makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

If previous methods does not work, here is another one (build in command):

###### zsh terminal

`$ history -p` (aka `fc -p`)

See: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This only temporarily clears on window instance. When you open up again, the history reappears. The previous answer is the correct one for macOS. And zsh does not recognize history -p.

Comment: @MariaCampbell, have you tried the above with a single terminal instance? For the moment I can't test this.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear all your history on Mac from the edit menu of the terminal, edit > clear scrollback or just enter 'alt + command + k'.